# dependency-check 3.1.1 IO Exception: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code

Tags: java, maven, security

So I'm trying to run dependency-check 3.1.1 both from the command line and from Maven and I'm getting...

> [ERROR] IO Exception: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code

I've this is from my laptop and I have a working connection to the feeds.  I did a little Wiresharking on the urls that are currently used and it looks like the location of the feeds may have changed?  I see this PR was submitted a couple of days ago:

https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/pull/1172#pullrequestreview-108378384

I think this will resolve the problem but since builds are currently broken for me I'm going to try to find a workaround that will set the URLs that seem to have been moved without warning by NIST.

Can anybody else confirm that they are having issues and provide an example of adjusting the location of the feeds on the command-line or in Maven?

Answer (score 1):

So I think the above mentioned pull request is actively being worked on and eventually you can just update to a newer version of Dependency Check, but for now if you want to make your builds pass and you have not set up a mirror you can make a change to the configuration to override the location of the feeds in mvn that looks something like this one...

> ```
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
>             <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1.1</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <failBuildOnCVSS>8</failBuildOnCVSS>
>                 <cveUrl20Modified>https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-Modified.xml.gz</cveUrl20Modified>
>                 <cveUrl20Base>https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-%d.xml.gz</cveUrl20Base>
>             </configuration>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>check</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```